# Only data from last JSON file in array is displayed

Tags: php, json

I am trying to display data from multiple `JSON` files using an `array`.

When using the code below, only the data from the last file in the array is displayed. How do I ensure that the data from all the files in the array are displayed?

If I change the order of the JSON files, still only the data from the last file in the array is displayed.

The array:

```
$homepage   = array();
$homepage[] = "http://linktojson.com/1/";
$homepage[] = "http://linktojson.com/2/";
$homepage[] = "http://linktojson.com/3/";
$homepage[] = "http://linktojson.com/4/";
$homepage[] = "http://linktojson.com/5/";
```

I then get the contents from the files in the array and decode it:

```
foreach ($homepage as $homepage2) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($homepage2, false));
}
```

And finally the value `ID` from each of the files in the array is echoed:

```
foreach ($data->Content->Catalog as $each) {
    echo $each->ID;
}
```

Comment: @TheCodesee, Is the links are valid json data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting `$data` with each iteration of your first `foreach` loop. If you move the second loop inside the first loop, you will see the IDs from each file.

```
foreach ($homepage as $homepage2) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($homepage2, false));
    foreach($data->Content->Catalog as $each){
        echo $each->ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel silly now.. if was simply an issue of nesting the `foreach` statement

Comment: Not sure if you might also be able to help with this, but I was looking at another thread and it showed me a function where I could list the value of `ID` in order from highest to lowest. It does it perfectly, but for each different array, the order starts again (if you get what I mean). Here's an example: https://3v4l.org/DXG85 - how would I change it so that all the whole array is from highest to lowest?

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: According `phpversion();`, it's 5.5.34

Comment: https://3v4l.org/HS7CZ @TheCodesee here is one way to do that, if I understand correctly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. However when I try to run it on my webhost, I get the error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` for this line of code: `$ids = array_merge($ids, array_column($data['info']['collection'], 'ID'));`. Is there a way to debug it?

Comment: Are you sure you did `json_decode($homepage2, true)`? The `true` makes it decode as an array of arrays instead of objects.

Comment: Yes, however I have to login through PHP with a cookie to access the files in the array. Would it matter if I added an extra parameter to the end: `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($homepage2, true, $context));`?

Comment: You need `, true` before the closing parenthesis of `json_decode`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me solve it :) One more query... is it possible to display the numbers from highest to lowest _(rather than lowest to highest)?

Comment: Sure, just `rsort` instead of `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `$data` in each iteration of your `foreach` loop. It is only remembering the last iteration.

You will want to put your `$data` evaluation code inside your first `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($homepage as $homepage2) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($homepage2, false));
    foreach($data->Content->Catalog as $each){
        echo $each->ID;
    }
}
```